# Updating failed while adding the shortcode on home page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I am displaying the recent post on the home page but I am getting an error. I am not able to save the shortcode on the home page.

I tried to display the `hello` text on the home page and that is displaying but after adding the below code it's not working.

Would you help me out?

[image]

```
function recentPost_on_home(){
$data='<div class="row">';
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5, // your 'x' goes here
                'nopaging' => true
                // possibly more arguments here
            );
            // set up new query
            $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            // loop through found posts
            if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
                while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $tyler_query->the_post();
                  $data.= '<div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="cs-post-item">
                            <div class="cs-post-category-icon">
                                <a href="'.the_permalink().'"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cs-post-thumb">
                                <a href="'.the_permalink().'"><img src="'.the_post_thumbnail_url().'" alt="'.the_title().'"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cs-post-inner">
                                <h3><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
                }
            } 
    $data.='</div>';

            return $data;    
}
add_shortcode( 'home_recent_post', 'recentPost_on_home' );
```

Comment: You have not defined which `post_type` you want to get in the shortcode.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal, Can you help me where should I define?

Comment: You no need to mention post_type if you are fetching wp default posts. Try get_posts($args) in your code.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal WP_Query default value for post_type is post.

Comment: @ParthShah Yes but it can help for debugging at least it is coming or not.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal, I tried my code on a single.php(After removing some echo and comms ) page and I am getting my output. But when I am creating a shortcode then I am getting the error.

Comment: @NarenVerma First check with `print_r($tyler_query)`. If you are getting something or not.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal, Yes, I am getting the output

Comment: @KrupalPanchal, I have $tyler_query->the_post(); inside while if I comment then I am getting error Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400556136 bytes)